# "reduction on infixes" in Racket?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, j, apl

I am working on a compiler pass and want to remove redundant `movq` instructions. For example, this list:

```
((movq a b)
 (movq b c)
 (movq c d)
 (movq d e))
```

should become `((movq a e))`.

Likewise, the list

```
((movq a b)
 (movq b c)
 (addq 20 c)
 (movq a b)
 (movq c d)
 (movq d e))
```

should reduce to this:

```
((movq a c)
 (addq 20 c)
 (movq a b)
 (movq c e))
```

My current (working) approach fuses the current and next `movq` instructions if the destination of the current matches the source of the next:

```lisp
(define (fuse-movq lst) ;; ((movq x y) (movq y z)) => ((movq x z))
  (match lst
    [`(,x) `(,x)]
    [else
     (define-values (x z) (values (car lst) (cddr lst)))
     (match* (x (cadr lst))
       [(`(movq ,a ,b) `(movq ,b ,c)) (fuse-movq (cons `(movq ,a ,c) z))]
       [(_ _) (append (list x) (fuse-movq (cdr lst)))])]))
```

This is fine, but I would much prefer to have the logic separate from the list traversal, something more like this:

```lisp
;; core logic
(define (fuse-movq x y)
  (match* (x y)
    [(`(movq ,a ,b) `(movq ,b ,c)) `(movq ,a ,c)]
    [(_ _) (x y)]))

;; list traversal handled by `foldl`
(foldl fuse-movq '() '((movq a b) (movq b c) (movq c d)))
```

Unfortunately `foldl` doesn't seem quite right, and `map` doesn't work because I want to process "this and the next element".

I tagged this with APL and J because the idiomatic way to apply infix function `f` to list `lst` in J is `f/\lst`.  Where `f/` is roughly translated as `apply f between the next 2 elements` and `\` is `prefix scan`. It's so common in those languages that I hoped to find a similar idiom in Racket.

In Racket, is there a way to decouple this "infix" kind of function behavior from the list traversal?

Comment: In your "core logic" fuse-moveq function, I don't understand your else case. Is `x` a function that you're applying? Or are you trying to make a list? Is it supposed to a single instruction or multiple instructions?

Comment: `x` and `y` are the current and next "instructions", respectively. I'm trying to filter the redundant `movq` instructions from a list, but I can see that's not obvious from my example, so I'll update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adjust this for your use case.

```
#lang racket

(define (transform xs)
  (for/fold ([prev (list (first xs))] #:result (reverse prev))
            ([item (in-list (rest xs))])
    (match* (prev item)
      [((list (list p q) xs ...) (list q r)) (cons (list p r) xs)]
      [(xs item) (cons item xs)])))

(transform '([a b] [c d] [d e] [e f] [s t] [g h] [h k] [x y] [y z]))
;=> '((a b) (c f) (s t) (g k) (x z))
```